# How can i give output exampleset of "Process Documents From Files" to Multiple Classifiers in rapid miner?

Tags: machine-learning, rapidminer, text-classification

I am working on parallel classifier combination and have a requirement in rapid miner to give output of "Process Documents from Files" operator to more than one classifier (L1, L2, L3). One way of doing it is to create three different processes and give each of them documents separately but that could be a performance bottleneck and i want to avoid it.

Is there any way to provide example set copies to classifiers (L1, L2, L3) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Multiply` operator to makes copies of example sets.